# Visual Joystick moving faster than my finger. why?

Tags: unity, mobile, joystick

First of all, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhicjf7-BYFJCNwduFVGzAkmhZTcBGV1/view?usp=sharing)'s the video of what my problem really is. (Sorry for bad quality)

As you can see, the red circle is the center of the visual joystick. The green one indicates my finger and the white circle is the handle of my joystick.

As you can see it works but the handle goes faster than my finger, I don't know why this happens

Here's the code for setting the handle's position:

```cs
            RawDirection = Input.GetTouch(CurrentFingerID).position -
                (Vector2)BGRect.position;

            if (RawDirection.magnitude > BGRect.sizeDelta.x / 2)
                RawDirection = RawDirection.normalized * BGRect.sizeDelta.x / 2;

            HandleRect.anchoredPosition = RawDirection;
```

meaning of the variables:

- `CurrentFingerID` is used to save which finger is on the joystick currently.
- `BGRect` is the RectTransform attached to the BG (see the pic below)
- `HandleRect` is the RectTransform attached to the Handle  (see the pic below)

And these are BG and Handle:

[image: BG and Handle]

BG and Handle settings:

[image: BG]

[image: Handle]

I think `RawDirection` should be divided by some number to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated and feel free to ask for additional info

Comment: Is the `BGRect` scaled?

Comment: @Mangata I doubted that the problem is scaling too but it's set to 1. I'll add their images in my questions

Comment: touch.Position is measured in screen pixels. RectTransform.anchoredPosition is measured in the units of its containing rect. Did you mean to convert between these coordinate systems explicitly, using [RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html)?

Comment: Oh, yes. I've tried that before but it didn't work. Now I tested it again, it works (with  some minor changes). I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I should have used `RectTransformUtility`:

```cs
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(ResponseArea, Input.touches[CurrentFingerID].position, null, out FingerPositionInRect);
RawDirection = FingerPositionInRect - ((BGRect.anchorMax + ResponseArea.sizeDelta) - BGRect.anchoredPosition;
```

(`ResponseArea` is the RectTransform of the Joystick)